# Highcharts Spider Chart, change axis ranges

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts' spider chart. No problem to load it.

I have a problem in axis ranges. Some data is between `0-100` and some is `1.000.000-10.000.000`. By default, highchart makes that `min : 0 and max` : `10.000.000` and some data's difference doesn't seem.

Could you help **please** ?

Thanks

Comment: please show your code...

Answer (score 0):

You need a `logarithmic` chart.

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'logarithmic'
}
```

[**Before**](http://jsfiddle.net/vN5np/) and [**After**](http://jsfiddle.net/LS8mV/)

Comment: Hi Ricardo,thank you for your response. I have tried to add type: 'logarithmic' in my chart but it doesn't work... could you show me a JsFiddle please?  Here is the basic spider chart I would like to customize : http://jsfiddle.net/v2YJp/

Comment: But how it should looks like? Because you can use tickPositioner or tickPositions and define your http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner / http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions

Comment: Hi Sebastian,The problem is that in my exampple : http://jsfiddle.net/v2YJp/ Headcount and Turnover axis have values but are too tiny compare to Average prices and Sold pieces so we can't see them. So I would to adjust those axis in order to display a chart you can easily understand like that : http://jsfiddle.net/v2YJp/1/

Comment: @L.Keysoft Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/v2YJp/2/. This is the same example you gave using logarithmic.